# Compile Jade with Koala

Tags: html, pug, koala

Hi there I have discovered Jade and I am trying to find out the best way to compile it to HTML. I currently use Koala to compile sass to css. However Koala doesn't seem to have native support for Jade.

Is there any plugin, extension for Koala that adds Jade compiling support?

I am using windows.

Thanks

Comment: The "best way" depends entirely on your setup as there are a lot of good ways to do it. Personally, I use NodeJS, Brunch and Jaded-Brunch and that works rather well. Not familiar with Koala, but unless my google-fu has failed me, I'm thinking [this](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=jade) is a good place for you to start.

Comment: A bit more use of google-fu, and [here](https://github.com/gaberankin/koala-jade) might be closer to what you seek.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I had a try at setting up the Koala Jade "plugin" but no luck. If I find something out that I manage to get working, will post it on here for anyone that may be looking for this info in the future.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue, I found the wrong [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) the first time, I take it you mean this [Koala](http://koala-app.com/), ignore the first link, the second seems valid. I tried downloading and it seems to work fine with [koala-jade](https://github.com/gaberankin/koala-jade). Though I did have to make some minor tweaks due to differences between Koala and Brunch. Ignore the "how to build section", just click ["view raw" on this page](https://github.com/gaberankin/koala-jade/blob/master/dist/jade.koala-compiler), which should start a download.

Comment: Then just follow the "How to install" directions. If you still have problems, then specify what the new issues are.

Comment: Thank you so much Nuclearman, Managed to get it working!!! I had been raking my brains for ages as to why it wasn't working.

Comment: That's good. Your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using Jade as well.

Prepros works very well for compiling Jade and Sass, and as a bonus it has built in FTP so you can upload your files immediately on saving.